# Why does format() turn numeric variables to character variables?

Tags: r, format, character, numeric

I'm building an example for a simple ANOVA demonstration and can't seem to set the decimal length without my numeric vectors turning to "character" vectors, is there a solution to this?

```
# use fGarch for building somewhat messy data
library(fGarch)
N = 30
set.seed(1976)
control = rsnorm(N, 25, 5, 1.8)
treatOne = rnorm(N, 25, 4)
treatTwo = rsnorm(N, 22, 5, -1.3)
treatThree = rsnorm(N, 20, 5, -1)

# bind groups into a single dataframe
mysteryOne = data.frame(control, treatOne, treatTwo, treatThree)
# "stack" the dataframe to combine it into one column
mysteryOne = stack(mysteryOne)
# rename the columns
library(plyr)
mysteryOne = rename(mysteryOne, c("values" = "anxiety", "ind" = "condition"))
# replace the experimental "condition" values with a "group code" 
mysteryOne$condition = c(rep(0, N), rep(1, N), rep(2, N), rep(3, N))

# specify vector types
mysteryOne[, 1] = as.numeric(mysteryOne[, 1])
mysteryOne[, 2] = as.factor(mysteryOne[, 2])

# restrict the numeric vector to two decimal points
mysteryOne[, 1] = format(round(mysteryOne[, 1], 2), nsmall = 2)

str(mysteryOne)
```

Comment: just format __after__ doing all calculations.

Comment: Because that's what the `format` function does. See the helpfile `?format`. If you want to display floating point numbers with greater precision, change your options: `pi; options(digits = 20); pi`.

Comment: Thanks, specifying the type after formatting is the default approach I'm going with now. I was wondering if perhaps I was leaving something out of the format() command. This statement in the ?format() help file led me to think I was missing something: "Numeric vectors are encoded with the minimum number of decimal places needed to display all the elements to at least the digits significant digits."

Answer (score 0):

You can round if you really want to throw away the information:

```
head(round(mysteryOne[, 1], 2))
# [1] 19.99 26.39 30.39 20.31 21.32 23.22
```

Pretty-printing is a text formatting problem. So the solutions give you strings:

```
head(format(mysteryOne[, 1], nsmall = 2L, digits = 2))
# [1] "19.99" "26.39" "30.39" "20.31" "21.32" "23.22"
```

Formatting the output then coercing it *back* to numeric is almost certainly not what you want.